# How to calculate the force drop due to multiple thrusters firing?

Tags: propulsion

When multiple thrusters are connected to one pressurized propellant tank and multiple thrusters are fired simultaneously, this will cause a pressure drop in the supplying pipes and as such a drop in the force produced by each thruster.

In [this](http://ssl.mit.edu/spheres/library/Thruster_calibration1.pdf) thruster calibration exercise, this force drop is experimentally determined. Does anyone know how to do this theoretically?

Comment: How is the propellant tank pressurized?

Comment: The tank is filled with a propellant and a pressurant gas. The system operates in blow-down mode.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if the tank was pressurized through a regulator.